# How do I improve performance on a MySQL query with NULL?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have several million records in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_store_email` (`store_id`,`email`),
  KEY `index_store_phone` (`store_id`,`phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Query #1** takes ~800ms:
`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `store_id` = 1; ``

**Query #2** takes ~1.5ms:
`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `store_id` = 1 AND `email` IS NULL; ``

**Query #3** takes a whopping **5 seconds**:
`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `store_id` = 1 AND `email` IS NOT NULL; ``

Notes:

- I've simplified the table to ask the question, but the query is identical.
- Yes, my table is optimized.
- Yes, both fields are indexed, see the create syntax above.
- There are only a few `store_id`s, but every record has one.
- There are very few customers with `email` set to `null`.

I find a few things strange here:

1. Query #1 is simplest! There are only a few possible INT values. Shouldn't it be fastest?
2. Why is Query #3 so slow? I could cut the time in half by doing the other two queries, and subtracting #1 from #2, but I shouldn't have to.

Any thoughts on this seemingly basic question? Feel like I'm missing something simple. Did I sleep through a class in db school?

Comment: Are you looking to get the count of all customers in that store, or are you looking to do something else? I ask because adding a LIMIT to your query would drastically optimize your performance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `EXPLAIN`? My guess is that it's a lot slower because of the data in the table. If there are only a few rows with `email = NULL` then it can easily use the index and return quite fast. The first query is slower because it has to walk through many more rows, if there are only a few different `store_id` results MySQL might decide that walking through the entire table is faster than walking through the index. Which can be the wrong choice

Comment: @zsawaf: it's a `COUNT(*)` query, how would a limit help in this case?

Comment: @zsawaf: Good idea, but `LIMIT` is not an option in these queries, and as @Wolph points out, never an option for `COUNT(*)` queries.

Comment: @Wolph: The `EXPLAIN` shows everything is keyed and in working order. What should I be looking for?

Comment: @neokio: look at the `rows`. It should tell you how many rows were examined to return the results.

Comment: Additionally, the `possible_keys` tells you which indices are possible for the current query and the `key` indicates which index (if any) was actually used.

Comment: Correct, that's why I was asking if you wanted to count all rows, or if you had a different query in mind. If what Wolph suggested doesn't help, the only other thing I can think of is to split up the load into different databases, and simultaneously retrieve queries.

Comment: @Wolph: You're totally right, it's using the wrong `key`, though the right one is listed in `possible_keys`. There's no way to tell it which index to use, is there?

Comment: I'm going to revise the post to better represent my actual syntax.

Comment: @Wolph: Check out the syntax. Your suggestion revealed that Query #3 was inexplicably keying off of `index_store_phone`. Removing it solved the immediate problem, the Q3 now takes 1.4 seconds. But what will happen when I add that index back in later?

Comment: In some cases MySQL guesses wrong... you can force MySQL to use the index: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: @Wolph: Excellent, `USE INDEX` within a query is a revelation. You've just improved my game. I think others might benefit as well. Rehash these tips into an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Get rid of the store_id index

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: If mysql is using the wrong index in this simple table, file a bug at `bugs.mysql.com`.

Comment: If there are "several million rows", why does it say `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`?  Perhaps that is an _old_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?  And maybe something else changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At times the MySQL query parser guesses wrong when it decides which indices to use. For cases like these the index hints can be useful (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

To force the use of an index:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

To force the use of an index including replacing table scans:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 FORCE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

To ignore a certain index:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 IGNORE INDEX (col3_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

To debug which index is being used the `EXPLAIN` statement can be used: (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolph. Also worth mentioning how useful `EXPLAIN` is for revealing hiccups in the query parser.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the index with just `(store_id)`; it is redundant with two other indexes.

This will probably also obviate the need for `FORCE INDEX`, etc.

`INDEX(store_id, email)` works for all three queries.